# HttpURLConnection "An unexpected error occurred."

Tags: java, web-services, http

From my little knowledge of 500 errors I understand it is a server error. But what could be the root cause behind something like this? Could it be on my end?

The error i'm getting is:

```
{"status":500,"error":"An unexpected error occurred."}
```

Could it have to do with my headers i.e missing one? From what i've found from testing the error changes from 400 errors i.e 401 after adding the user agent header.

my code looks as follows:

```
String url="https://api.gotinder.com/auth";
    URL object=new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Host", "host url");
    //con.setRequestProperty("content-Length" , "287");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent" , "Tinder/4.0.4");
    con.setRequestProperty("facebook_token", "token");
    //con.setRequestProperty("facebook_id", "id");

    System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
```

Side note: This is all for educational purpose. I got intrigued.

Comment: Could you please share the URL? As the URL is not correct `String url="url";`

Comment: 'Could it have to do with my headers' : I don't think so, as I executed same code with valid url and got OK code 200.

Comment: I think you are missing some headers  like Authorization Basic . Try hitting it using some rest client

Comment: Postman is giving me the same error code strange.. @Barath I don't think Authorization would help here but i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was passing my token as a Property and not a part of the body.

code:

```
String urlstr = "https://api.gotinder.com/auth";
    String params = "facebook_token=" + this.fb_token;
    URL url = new URL(urlstr);
    HttpURLConnection urlconn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlconn.setDoInput(true);
    urlconn.setDoOutput(true);
    urlconn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlconn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Tinder/3.0.4 (iPhone; iOS 7.1; Scale/2.00)");
    urlconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
    OutputStream os = urlconn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(params);
    writer.close();
    os.close();

    if (urlconn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlconn.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";

        StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = bR.readLine()) != null) {
            responseStrBuilder.append(line);
        }
        urlconn.getInputStream().close();

        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(responseStrBuilder.toString());
        user_token = result.getString("token");
        System.out.println("User token is: " + user_token);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Want to print error here had getting data...");
    }
```